# Form is not being posted back

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently working on create-post view of dashboard of my blogging site. I have used Aero template.

```
 @extends('Dashboard.Layout.master')
    @section('content')
        <section class="content blog-page">
            <div class="body_scroll">
                <div class="block-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-12">

                            <ul class="breadcrumb">
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index.html"><i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i>Computer Bitches</a></li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="blog-dashboard.html">Blog</a></li>
                                <li class="breadcrumb-item active"> New Post</li>

                            </ul>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-icon mobile_menu" type="button"><i class="zmdi zmdi-sort-amount-desc"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-icon float-right right_icon_toggle_btn" type="button"><i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <form method="post" action="{{route('dashboard.store.post')}}">
                                @method('post')
                                @csrf
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Blog title" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select class="mdb-select md-form form-control" multiple searchable="Search here..">
                                            <option>LARAVEL</option>
                                            <option>GIT</option>
                                            <option>AWS</option>
                                            <option>REACT</option>
                                            <option>PHP</option>
                                            <option>JAVASCRIPT</option>
                                            <option>CSS3</option>
                                            <option>HTML5</option>
                                            <option>WEB TECHNOLOGIES</option>
                                            <option>JQUERY</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <textarea id="editor" name="editor " class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="Enter your Content">
                                        </textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Save"/>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    @endsection
    @section('scripts')
        ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .then(editor => {
        document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML = editor.getData();
        })
        .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
        } );
    @endsection
```

I have tried all the possible ways, from posting back throuh jquery to removing elements and putting them back but no lock yet. It's been 10 hours still trying but I don't think I will find the solution. Thank you guys in advance for any leads.

Comment: For starters, most of your form elements don't have a name attribute.

Comment: Thank you but even when I add name in my inputs it's not posting back anyway.